# can CiviCRM replace Commerce?

Tags: commerce

From a quick look at the CiviCRM demo, it looks like it handles everything a non-profit would use Drupal Commerce for - primarily, memberships, events, and donations.

Do most people use CiviCRM alongside Commerce, or instead of Commerce?

If you use both, what are some of the things Commerce handles that you can't do in CiviCRM?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SE!  I can't answer the Commerce aspect as I don't use it, but yes CiviCRM can handle memberships, events and donations and many non-profits run solely on CiviCRM without Commerce.

Comment: For folk who have products to sell then Commerce is necessary. We have done work to integrate Commerce with CiviCRM, so for example a purchase of a membership 'product' via Commerce results in a civicrm membership being created. This gives those sites the best of both worlds as they can now eg sell the book and the t-shirt and offer a discount if they purchaser also buys a membership. The integration work may be fairly custom at this point so may not have been shared publicly yet, but our aim is to do so.

Comment: Pete, isn't that the perfect answer?